# Setting NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as false is not blocking HTTP requests in WKWebView in iOS Application

Tags: swift, httprequest, wkwebview, app-transport-security, nsapptransportsecurity

We are trying to **block** HTTP requests in WKWebView using **App Transport Security: NSAllowsArbitraryLoads**. However, it is not working in the below mentioned scenario

**Step 1:** Set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as '**false**' in Info.plist. Load an HTTP request in WKWebView. The request is blocked as expected
**Step 2:** Set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as '**true**' in Info.plist. Load the same HTTP request in WKWebView. The request is loaded successfully in the webview as expected.
**Step 3:** Set NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as '**false**' in Info.plist. Load the same HTTP request in WKWebView. **The request is loaded successfully instead of blocking the request.**

Note: Just to ensure this is not happening due to cache issue, we also tried by setting the cache policy of the request as **URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData**. However, this is not helping us to resolve the issue.

Could you help us resolve this issue?

**Update 1:** Added screenshot of the [info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB9L7.png) App Transport Security setting and [webview load request method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN4RR.png)

**Update 2:** URL Request

```
- url : http://www.httpurl.com/
- cachePolicy : 4
- timeoutInterval : 60.0
- mainDocumentURL : nil
- networkServiceType : C.NSURLRequestNetworkServiceType
- allowsCellularAccess : true
- httpMethod: GET
- allHTTPHeaderFields : nil
- httpBody : nil
- httpBodyStream : nil
- httpShouldHandleCookies : true
- httpShouldUsePipelining : false
```

Comment: Paraphrasing your issue is nice but we can't see your code to actually diagnose the problem. It could be a logic problem, it could be a compile-time/run-time thing... You have to give use more.

Comment: @Benjamin added screenshot of code and info.plist's App Transport Security setting

Comment: Have you debugged your code the 3rd case by setting a breakpoint in that `loadRequest` function before the guard? Does the guard return and the view just doesn't change but it looks like it loaded again?

Comment: Also, please review [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should not be posting pictures of code.

Comment: @Benjamin, yes with help of breakpoints, I did debug to see if the guard returns. However, the guard does not fail, and the webview loads the request successfully in the 3rd case. Attaching the urlRequest object as an update to the question.